# Master Page in Visual Studio 2012 doesn't want to load in web browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, web-applications, master-pages

I am trying to build a master page for a website in ASP.NET, and after several trials, I couldn't display the page in my web browser. I have changed browsers thinking that source of the problem might be that. However the same problem is occurring: I get exactly a blank page without anything on it: In the designer of visual Studio, I can see a sample view of how the website will look like (I have all the files needed for the pictures of the background and the profile picture.) 
 What might be the problem?

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

            <link href="/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <style>

    header {
      text-align: center;
      background-image: url("/Pictures/Harvard-widerBlurred.jpg");
      background-size: cover;
      color: white;
    }
    a {
      color: white;
    }
    h1 {
      font-size: 70px;
    }
    img {
      margin: 40px 0px 0px 0px;
      border: 7px solid white;
      border-radius: 20px;
    }
    ul {
      padding: 10px;
      background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    }
    li {
      display: inline;
      padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    }
    article{
      max-width: 500px;
      padding: 20px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    @media (max-width: 500px){
      li{
        display: block;
        padding: 5px; 
      }
      h1{
        font-size: 36px;
      }
      body {
        background: red;
      }
    }
  </style>

                <header>
                    <img src="/Pictures/GoExchangelogo.jpg">
                    <h1>GoExchange!</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a>Us</li>
                        <li><a href="#">My Appointment</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">My Application</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </header>
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: you might be overriding the content placeholder

Comment: Is your HTML actually structured like this?

Comment: @DrewKennedy Yes! I believe so!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why exactly are you attempting to create an HTML document inside an HTML document?

Comment: @DrewKennedy I think that that was not my purpose. However, even if after deleting the second `<!DOCTYPE html>` the problem is still the same!
Thank you

Comment: What do you mean exactly? @DanielA.White

Comment: your content page might be modifying what is in the placeholder.

Comment: @DanielA.White I arrived to a partial solution.However, what I don't understand is that the content placeholder is made so that you put content into it. but when I put the content of the master page into it,I don't get anything displayed. However when I put the content outside the content placeholder. I get the whole design displayed, any ideas?